# No qualifying bean of type 'Mapper.class' available

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I hava a project using springboot 2.5.14 version. When i try to run it gives an error like

> Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'requestFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'logService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'logServiceImpl' defined in file ...: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'demo.mapper.LogMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Mapstruct version: 1.4.2.Final and Lombok is 1.8.24

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>  <!-- IMPORTANT - LOMBOK BEFORE MAPSTRUCT -->
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My code is like below:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

  @Autowired
  private LogService logService;

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    log.info("servlet filter initialized..");
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse httpResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, httpResponse);
    } finally {
      httpAnalyze(request);      
    }
  }
  
  private void httpAnalyze(ServletRequest request) {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    // It makes some analysis and log them
    logService.insertLog("...", "...");

  }
}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class LogServiceImpl implements LogService {

  private final LogRepository logRepository;
  private final LogMapper logMapper;
  
  private Long insertLog(String note, String content) {

    LogDtoBuilder logBuilder = LogDto.builder();

    InsuredNoContextData insuredNoContextData = HclmRequestContextHolder.getInsuredNoContextData();

    initInsuredNo(logBuilder, insuredNoContextData);

    LogDto logDto = logBuilder.note(getNote(note)).content(content).build();

    Long logId = logRepository.save(logMapper.convertToEntity(logDto)).getLogId();


    return logId;
  }
}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface LogMapper extends BaseMapper<LogEntity, LogDto, LogDto> {

}
```

I tried many solution on the net but couldn't find out.

Comment: Not entirely sure but after removing spring-boot-starter-validation dependency from pom.xml, problem solved